# Effect size for a 2 x 1 Chi-Square test

Tags: chi-squared-test, effect-size, contingency-tables

I have analysed a series of 2 x 1 Chi-Squares in SPSS but there was no option to calculate an effect size. I understand that I can't use Cramer's V for a 2 x 1 contingency table. Should I use a proportion test to find the effects size and report this after my Chi-Square? I want to find out participants are significantly more likely to 'strongly agree/agree' than 'disagree/strongly disagree' to a set of questions. There are 11 separate questions in total so I have run 11 chi-square statistics. I now want to calculate the effect size for each.

Comment: By "2x1 chi square" you mean a one-sample, two tailed test of proportions?

Comment: Yes - It is a 2 x 1 contingency table, just comparing 'strongly agree/agree' versus 'strongly disagree/disagree'. The next row down is expected frequency. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're testing whether the proportion is 50% in each?

Comment: I am testing whether the proportions are significant with the chi-square, then I want to calculate the effect size.

Comment: "whether the proportions are significant" isn't a hypothesis; it could mean almost anything, depending on your actual hypothesis. Please don't replace a precise statement with a quite ambiguous one. Either you're testing what I asked or you're testing something else, but then you need to be as explicit as I was about exactly what you're testing.

Comment: I am testing whether 'strongly agree/agree' is significantly different to 'strongly disagree/disagree'

Comment: Okay, but with exactly two groups that's testing whether the proportions differ from 50%. Just needed to be sure it was in fact a simple two tailed, one-sample proportions test. It is.

Comment: That is correct, yes

Comment: @Glen_b I have just found one of your answers on another chi square question and I think that it solves my problem: 
'If you place the goodness-of-fit chi-square value in that formula in place of the usual independence chi-square, while you could not (to my mind) reasonably call that Cramer's V (since it doesn't measure association), it would be a perfectly good measure of concentration. It's 0 when the categories are perfectly evenly represented and it's 1 when all the values are in a single category'. So in the formula where = (k - 1) would the value be 0? So Cramer's V =  sqrt(X2/n x 0) ?